# Filter a JSON file into different JSON files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have got the following JSON file with the keys being dates:

```
main  [{"2018-01-01":277,"2018-01-08":361,
      "2018-02-05":357,"2018-02-12":367,
      "2018-03-05":481,"2018-03-12":445,
      "2018-04-02":484,"2018-04-09":345}]
```

I am trying to separate them in 3 different JSON files with a file per month eg.
I have try this:

```
var jan =[];
for(key in main){
   if(key.substring(0,7) == "2018-01"){
      jan.push(main[key],key)
   }
}
```

But am having this:

```
["2018-01-01", 277, "2018-01-08", 361, "2018-01-15", 426, "2018-01-22", 389, "2018-01-29", 394]
```

But I would like this instead:

`jan = {"2018-01-01":277,"2018-01-08":361, ..}
 fev = {"2018-02-05":357,"2018-02-12":367, ...}`

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Show us your efforts, and ask about the specific issue that you're facing.

Comment: JSON is a *string format* that represents an object, not a *variable type*.

Comment: Use this `let f = (m,r={})=>(Object.keys(main[0]).map(x=>x.split('-')[1]==m?r[x]=main[0][x]:0),r);` in this way `let jan = f('01');` https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/n5apvw8s/18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and use `split` to get the month.

```js
let main = {"2018-01-01": 277,"2018-01-08": 361,"2018-02-05": 357,"2018-02-12": 367,"2018-03-05": 481,"2018-03-12": 445,"2018-04-02": 484,"2018-04-09": 345};

let result = Object.keys(main).reduce((c, v) => {
  let m = v.split('-')[1];                //Get the month
  c[m] = c[m] || {};                      //Initialize if month does not exist
  c[m][v] = main[v];                      //Assign the value
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could group the items by month using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```
var main = {
    "2018-01-01":277,"2018-01-08":361,
    "2018-02-05":357,"2018-02-12":367,
    "2018-03-05":481,"2018-03-12":445,
    "2018-04-02":484,"2018-04-09":345
};

var result = Object.keys(main).reduce((r, a) => {
    var month = a.substr(5, 2);
    r[month] = r[month] || [];
    var obj = {};
    obj[a] = main[a];
    r[month].push(obj);
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));
```

at this stage the result will look like this:

```
{
    "01": [{ "2018-01-01": 277 }, { "2018-01-08": 361 }],
    "02": [{ "2018-02-05": 357 }, { "2018-02-12": 367 }],
    "03": [{ "2018-03-05": 481 }, { "2018-03-12": 445 }],
    "04": [{ "2018-04-02": 484 }, { "2018-04-09": 345 }]
}
```

Now it should be trivial to loop through the keys of this result and merge the items.